# Multiple Youtube channels on 1 account. How to restrict provided API key to only 1 channel?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need the Youtube API key from a client just to populate a link list of their recent videos.

The client expressed they have one account with multiple youtube channels attached to the one google account. For security they are asking if the API can be restricted to one youtube channel. I just fetched the data and displayed it im not a youtube API expert so i am unsure how to direct them. They want the key they provide to only allow data fetched from the specific channel? Is that possible in the API settings when creating the key?

(google search was unhelpful and the docs didnt really mention multiple channels)

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but you can restrict the channel in the api call to fetch data.  I feel like the channel specification is probably a required field, so I don't know why they would need to restrict the key.  Basically, if there's a person who shouldn't be seeing some data, they probably shouldn't be giving them their key in the first place.  Maybe a little more specific use scenario would help me understand why they want to do it, and what the options might be.

Answer (score 0):

Api keys are only able to access public data. For example public videos uploaded to youtube.

If you want to access private user data then you are going to need to use Oauth2 and authorize the user.

How you authorize the user depends upon which language you are using.   You should consult the documentation [Authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)

When you authorize a user then will be able to pick which channel to grant you access to. This will give you an access token that you can use to access the data on that channel.